# android implement countdown timer clock

Tags: android

I am newbie to android, I need to develop a countdown timer clock component. The component just looks like stopwatch.

Please help me in this.

Thanks
mini.

Comment: check [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using `CountDownTimer` you can do this,and on time is complete `onFinish` is called.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {//here time completing is 30 seconds

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        //finish here ,do stuff here
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank u Samir, I have gone through this count down timer as well as customize the analog clock.